# Lemmatization not working on words starting with capitol letters

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am working on a project that uses StanfordNLP. One of the function in the project it to extract all nouns from a piece of text and lemmatize each noun. I am extracting the nouns using the below code

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, parse, natlog, openie");
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);


        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);

        pipeline.annotate(document);         

        List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);

        for(CoreMap sentence: sentences) {

          SemanticGraph dependencies = sentence.get(BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
          List<String> Nouns = Extractnouns(dependencies.typedDependencies(), sentence); 
        }

     private List<String> Extractnouns(Collection<TypedDependency> tdl, CoreMap sentence) { 
     List<String> concepts=new ArrayList<String>();
     for (TypedDependency td : tdl) 
            {

                String govlemma = td.gov().lemma(); 
                String deplemma = td.dep().lemma(); 
                String deptag=td.dep().tag();
                String govtag=td.gov().tag();
                if(deptag!=null && deptag.contains("NN") )
                {
                     concepts.add(deplemma);
                 }
                if(govtag!=null && govtag.contains("NN") )
                {
                     concepts.add(govlemma);
                 }
             }
         return concepts;
```

}

It is working as expected but for some words the lemmatization is not working. I observed that some of the nouns that come as the first word in a sentence have this problem. Example: "Protons and electrons both carry an electrical charge." Here the word "Protons" is not getting converted to "proton" on applying lemma. Same with with some other nouns too.

Could you please tell me a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a part of speech tagging error.  "Protons" gets labelled with "NNP" not "NNS", so lemmatization isn't performed on it.

You could try running on lower-cased versions of the text, I note in that case it does the right thing.